# SQL error message when querying table containing one varbinary (blob) field

Tags: sql, delphi, blob, varbinary

We are using Delphi XE3 together with a TSQLDataSet and a TClientDataset to read a table into memory from SQL server 2012.

The table contains various fields, one of them a blob "varbinary(max)" where we store the content from a text file.

My problem is that we get an error message saying "connection is busy with results for another command" when we do a open on the ClientDataset.
The commandtext is a simple "select * from tablename".

This happens only if there are more than one item in the table. It also happens only if there are data in the blob field (<> NULL).

Everything work fine if we add a second varbinary field to the table. The second field does not have to contain any data.

This is driving me crazy, please help.

EDIT: As a workaround we have simply added a "dummy" varbinary field to the table. Because of this strange behavior, we have come to the conclusion that this has to be a bug in the TClientDataset component. Tried to do the same in a older version of delphi (XE2 SP3) with the same result.

Comment: Is poFetchBlobOnDemand part of your ProviderFlags? What happen if you directly open the SQLDataSet? What happens if you use a TSQLQuery?

Comment: poFetchBlobOnDemand is unchecked on the provider component. All settings on the components are the default ones you get when you add them to delphi's form. If I do an open on the SQLDataset I will not get the error, but then I am unable later to access the data on the ClientDataset because I get the error message that I can not access a "closed dataset". I have not tried TSQLQuery, as that is not an option for us. We need to have the data in a ClientDataset as we are displaying it in a grid, and need to be able to edit it's data.

Comment: Adding that the blob field does not have to be one of the fields on the ClientDataset in order for the error to occur. It is enough that I add the tables primary key as the only field on the ClientDataset.